# Send XML string to jquery ajax from VB.NET WEB METHOD

Tags: xml, jquery, xml-parsing, dataset, webmethod

This is my jquery ajax call:

```
 var result = $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "messages.aspx/GetMessages",
                data: jsonText,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "text",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);

                },
                failure: function (msg) {
                    alert(msg);
                },
                error: function (xhr, err) {
                    alert(err);
                    alert(xhr);
                }
            });
```

and this is my web method:

```
<WebMethod()>
Public Shared Function GetMessages(clientID As String, CommandText As String) As String

    Dim dsMain As New DataSet()
    Try
    Dim objConnectionStringSettings As ConnectionStringSettings = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("nXstepRevampDevConnectionString")
    strConnectionString = objConnectionStringSettings.ConnectionString
    Dim cnn As New SqlConnection()
    cnn.ConnectionString = strConnectionString
    cmd.Connection = cnn
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    cmd.CommandText = "GetAll_Employee_Messages"
    cmd.Parameters.Clear()
    AddParameter("@EmployeeID", Convert.ToInt32(clientID))

    dsMain = ExecuteDataSet()

    If dsMain.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
        Dim flag As Boolean = True
    End If

Catch ex As Exception


End Try

Return dsMain.GetXml


End Function
```

But when i return the xml string to my jquery ajax call, I get some undesired output. I want below output (alert),

```
"<NewDataSet>    <Table>      <EID>1</EID>      <IsRead>false</IsRead>      <ID>1</ID>      <ClientID>1</ClientID>      <Title>Dot Net Training Session</Title>      <Message>Dot Net Training Session Included&lt;br&gt;ASP.net&lt;br&gt;C#&lt;br&gt;Vb.net&lt;br&gt;SQL Server&lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;</Message>      <Priority>1</Priority>      <MessagePostDate>2013-11-01T14:56:11.733+05:00</MessagePostDate>      <MessageStartDate>2013-11-21T00:00:00+05:00</MessageStartDate>      <MessageExpiryDate>2013-11-30T00:00:00+05:00</MessageExpiryDate>      <Deleted>false</Deleted>      <IsVideoMessage>false</IsVideoMessage>      <IsVideoMessageType>0</IsVideoMessageType>      <MessVideoPath />      <MessVideoName />      <UpdatedBy>3</UpdatedBy>      <UpdatedOn>2013-11-21T11:26:43.897+05:00</UpdatedOn>    </Table>    <Table>      <EID>1</EID>      <IsRead>false</IsRead>      <ID>2</ID>      <ClientID>1</ClientID>      <Title>Crunch Fitness Officially Crowned the Single Greatest Gym Franchise of All Time</Title>      <Message>saefasdf asdf asdf asdf</Message>      <Priority>2</Priority>      <MessagePostDate>2013-11-12T21:52:01.013+05:00</MessagePostDate>      <MessageStartDate>2013-11-21T00:00:00+05:00</MessageStartDate>      <MessageExpiryDate>2013-11-22T00:00:00+05:00</MessageExpiryDate>      <Deleted>false</Deleted>      <IsVideoMessage>false</IsVideoMessage>      <IsVideoMessageType>0</IsVideoMessageType>      <MessVideoPath>Messages/Mess2/</MessVideoPath>      <MessVideoName>Wildlife.flv</MessVideoName>      <UpdatedBy>3</UpdatedBy>      <UpdatedOn>2013-11-21T11:27:01.23+05:00</UpdatedOn>    </Table>    <Table>      <EID>1</EID>      <IsRead>false</IsRead>      <ID>3</ID>      <ClientID>1</ClientID>      <Title>test</Title>      <Message>sdahjkhdfkjsanhdf</Message>      <Priority>3</Priority>      <IsVideoMessage>false</IsVideoMessage>      <IsVideoMessageType>0</IsVideoMessageType>    </Table>  </NewDataSet>" String
```

But i get the below output in alert:

```
"{"NewDataSet\u003e\r\n  \u003cTable\u003e\r\n    \u003cEID\u003e1\u003c/EID\u003e\r\n    \u003cIsRead\u003efalse\u003c/IsRead\u003e\r\n    \u003cID\u003e1\u003c/ID\u003e\r\n    \u003cClientID\u003e1\u003c/ClientID\u003e\r\n    \u003cTitle\u003eDot Net Training Session\u003c/Title\u003e\r\n    \u003cMessage\u003eDot Net Training Session Included&lt;br&gt;ASP.net&lt;br&gt;C#&lt;br&gt;Vb.net&lt;br&gt;SQL Server&lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;\u003c/Message\u003e\r\n    \u003cPriority\u003e1\u003c/Priority\u003e\r\n    \u003cMessagePostDate\u003e2013-11-01T14:56:11.733+05:00\u003c/MessagePostDate\u003e\r\n    \u003cMessageStartDate\u003e2013-11-21T00:00:00+05:00\u003c/MessageStartDate\u003e\r\n    \u003cMessageExpiryDate\u003e2013-11-30T00:00:00+05:00\u003c/MessageExpiryDate\u003e\r\n    \u003cDeleted\u003efalse\u003c/Deleted\u003e\r\n    \u003cIsVideoMessage\u003efalse\u003c/IsVideoMessage\u003e\r\n    \u003cIsVideoMessageType\u003e0\u003c/IsVideoMessageType\u003e\r\n    \u003cMessVideoPath /\u003e\r\n    \u003cMessVideoName /\u003e\r\n    \u003cUpdatedBy\u003e3\u003c/UpdatedBy\u003e\r\n    \u003cUpdatedOn\u003e2013-11-21T11:26:43.897+05:00\u003c/UpdatedOn\u003e\r\n  \u003c/Table\u003e\r\n  \u003cTable\u003e\r\n    \u003cEID\u003e1\u003c/EID\u003e\r\n    \u003cIsRead\u003efalse\u003c/IsRead\u003e\r\n    \u003cID\u003e2\u003c/ID\u003e\r\n    \u003cClientID\u003e1\u003c/ClientID\u003e\r\n    \u003cTitle\u003eCrunch Fitness Officially Crowned the Single Greatest Gym Franchise of All Time\u003c/Title\u003e\r\n    \u003cMessage\u003esaefasdf asdf asdf asdf\u003c/Message\u003e\r\n    \u003cPriority\u003e2\u003c/Priority\u003e\r\n    \u003cMessagePostDate\u003e2013-11-12T21:52:01.013+05:00\u003c/MessagePostDate\u003e\r\n    \u003cMessageStartDate\u003e2013-11-21T00:00:00+05:00\u003c/MessageStartDate\u003e\r\n    \u003cMessageExpiryDate\u003e2013-11-22T00:00:00+05:00\u003c/MessageExpiryDate\u003e\r\n    \u003cDeleted\u003efalse\u003c/Deleted\u003e\r\n    \u003cIsVideoMessage\u003efalse\u003c/IsVideoMessage\u003e\r\n    \u003cIsVideoMessageType\u003e0\u003c/IsVideoMessageType\u003e\r\n    \u003cMessVideoPath\u003eMessages/Mess2/\u003c/MessVideoPath\u003e\r\n    \u003cMessVideoName\u003eWildlife.flv\u003c/MessVideoName\u003e\r\n    \u003cUpdatedBy\u003e3\u003c/UpdatedBy\u003e\r\n    \u003cUpdatedOn\u003e2013-11-21T11:27:01.23+05:00\u003c/UpdatedOn\u003e\r\n  \u003c/Table\u003e\r\n  \u003cTable\u003e\r\n    \u003cEID\u003e1\u003c/EID\u003e\r\n    \u003cIsRead\u003efalse\u003c/IsRead\u003e\r\n    \u003cID\u003e3\u003c/ID\u003e\r\n    \u003cClientID\u003e1\u003c/ClientID\u003e\r\n    \u003cTitle\u003etest\u003c/Title\u003e\r\n    \u003cMessage\u003esdahjkhdfkjsanhdf\u003c/Message\u003e\r\n    \u003cPriority\u003e3\u003c/Priority\u003e\r\n    \u003cIsVideoMessage\u003efalse\u003c/IsVideoMessage\u003e\r\n    \u003cIsVideoMessageType\u003e0\u003c/IsVideoMessageType\u003e\r\n  \u003c/Table\u003e\r\n\u003c/NewDataSet\u003e"}"
```

I m getting the data but the tags are changing to some strange words and is causing problem...i can't figure out the problem, plz help in solving this.Moreover i checked the value before retruning from function and it is fine. But i don'r know what happens to it when i alert it in jquery ajax success function. Kindly help

Answer (score 0):

you should change `dataType: "text"` to `dataType: "xml"` because `dataType` represents the type of data you are expecting form the server.

Comment: get ride of `dataType` and in success function replace `alert(data);` with `alert(data.d);`

Comment: i tried data type = 'json' and alert(data.d)...and it worked...any way thanks @Mohammad Shahrouri